# How to delete duplicate rows in Oracle with the same geometry

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry, shapefile

There is a table that includes points and their geometry, and I want to delete duplicate rows based on the geometry column. Here is the code:

```
DELETE FROM NODE
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM NODE
GROUP BY CITYID, GEOMETRY);
```

However, I receive this error:

> 22901. 00000 -  "cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type"
>        *Cause:    Comparison of VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
>        was attempted in the absence of a MAP or ORDER method.
>        *Action:   Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type.
>        What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the type of GEOMETRY column?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DBMS_LOB.COMPARE()` (if the column is a LOB object):

```
DELETE 
  FROM NODE A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM NODE B
                WHERE DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(A.GEOMETRY, B.GEOMETRY) = 0
                  AND A.CITYID = B.CITYID
                  AND A.ROWID > B.ROWID);
```